# Autocomplete working in online example but not on Fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Autocomplete is working in the [example](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default) here but not in [my try](http://jsfiddle.net/9krumyd7/). What am I missing?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might be trying to edit the autocomplete before the DOM is ready, try wrapping that part in a document ready block.

Comment: Your script references has issues. Check this one : http://jsfiddle.net/9krumyd7/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/34daof5f/

Comment: @DinoMyte that works too lol, beat me to it

Comment: Your links in jsFiddle were bad. Works fine if you link to the libraries correctly http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9krumyd7/4/

Comment: @Wobbles: You are adding references directly in the DOM. Just another way to make it work.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work here:
http://www.inspuratesystems.com/tuitionteacher/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add jQuery and jQuery UI to your jsfiddle (from the jsfiddle sidebar under **Frameworks & Extensions**).

**EDIT:**

Your code in (inspuratesystems.com/tuitionteacher) does not work because the jQuery library is not loaded. See the console in inspect element (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work here: inspuratesystems.com/tuitionteacher

Comment: I edited my answer, the jQuery library is not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the call of external files (jQuery and jQuery UI). Try this [now](http://jsfiddle.net/9krumyd7/6/)

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: His include URLs look proper to me.